# Hash how to push new and update current

Tags: java, hash

I have `Hash` like

```
 private Map<String, List<MEventDto>> mEventsMap;
```

Then I want to check if the key already exist. If it exist, I will just update the values and I will add a new key. How can I do this.

I try like:

```
for (MEventDto mEventDto : mEventList) {
    String mEventKey = mEventDto.getMEventKey();
    String findBaseMEvent = mEventKey.split("_")[0];

    if (mEventsMap.get(findBaseMEvent ) != null) {
        // create new one
        mEventsMap.put(findBaseMEvent , mEventDtoList);
    } else {
        // just update it
         mediationEventsMap.
    }
}
```

How can I do this with `Hash`?

Comment: Check out: - [Map#containsKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Map#containsKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) to check whether a key is present or not: -

So, in your case, it would be like this: -

```
if (mEventsMap.containsKey(findBaseMEvent)) {
      // just update the enclosed list
      mEventsMap.get(findBaseMEvent).add("Whatever you want");            
} else {
      // create new entry
      mEventsMap.put(findBaseMEvent , mEventDtoList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[HashMap containsKey()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) You can use this method

```
 boolean    containsKey(Object key) 
      Returns true if this map contains a mapping for the specified key.
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do it as follows:

```
String mEventKey = mEventDto.getMEventKey();
String findBaseMEvent = mEventKey.split("_")[0];

List<MEventDto> list = mEventsMap.get(findBaseMEvent);
/* 
 * If the key is not already present, create new list, 
 * otherwise use the list corresponding to the key.
 */
list = (list == null) ? new ArrayList<MEventDto>() : list;

// Add the current Dto to the list and put it in the map.
list.add(mEventDto);
mEventsMap.put(findBaseMEvent , mEventDtoList);
```